# Strange serial port read/write behaviour

Tags: .net, serial-port

In my .Net console app I have the following method that writes a small number of bytes (approx 20) to the serial port, then reads a response (again no more than 20 bytes). It's used for communicating with an external hardware device - sending it a request for data and getting the requested values back.

I've cut out superfluous code, port initialisation, variable declarations etc, but you can still see what it's doing:-

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

// Write the "request" bytes.
_port.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Console.WriteLine("After write: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
sw.Restart();

// Wait for response, but timeout after 100ms.
var timeoutCount = 0;
while (_port.BytesToRead == 0 && timeoutCount < 100)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    timeoutCount++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Waited: {0}, #loops: {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, timeoutCount);

if (_port.BytesToRead == 0)
{
    // Timed-out..
    return null;
}

// Read the response.
var receivedData = new byte[_port.BytesToRead];
_port.Read(receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length);

return receivedData;
```

My app calls the above code in a tight (almost continuous) loop. You'll notice I've added a couple of Console.WriteLines to output some timings, and I see very consistent figures like this:-

> ```
> After write: 0
> Waited: 14, #loops: 1
> After write: 0
> Waited: 14, #loops: 1
> After write: 0
> Waited: 14, #loops: 1
> ...and so on...
> ```

Clearly the write is happening very quickly, and the response is also arriving quickly as the app only goes through the `while` loop once, although I'm puzzled by why it shows 14ms when it's only done a single `Thread.Sleep(1)`.

Stranger still, f I do something else on the PC like open another window, have Chrome running, or even just move the mouse around, then I'll see figures like this:-

> ```
> After write: 0
> Waited: 4, #loops: 5
> After write: 0
> Waited: 2, #loops: 3
> After write: 0
> Waited: 2, #loops: 3
> After write: 0
> Waited: 1, #loops: 2
> After write: 0
> Waited: 3, #loops: 4
> ```

This is more like what I would expect from serial port code such as mine, and not the mysterious 14ms that I'm seeing when the PC is "idle". Any ideas as to what is going on?

It's causing me a problem because my app is required to perform approx 12 write/reads every 100ms. You can see from the second set of timings (a few ms each) that this is easily achievable, but when the PC is "idle" each write/read is taking 14ms, resulting in my app regularly missing data (which updates on the external device every 100ms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have real time requirements, but you are developing on a non-real time system (windows). Sleep(1) just tells the OS that your thread cannot be reactivated for at least 1ms, so it will go away for a minimum of 1ms, and it will come back when the scheduler gets to it.

The reason your mouse movement appears to make it behave better is because it causes the scheduler to be invoked much more frequently by all the mouse movement events.

Consider using a real time OS, or do not depend on windows for scheduling, though that might be difficult if your _port.write() blocks with system calls like WaitForSingleObject or Sleep. And you could also consider dropping any real time requirements, and just taking what you get from the serial port whenever you get it.

Comment: So even though the mouse events are occurring in a different window it's still making the scheduler "service" *my* app more regularly? Is there any way to control/configure the scheduler to achieve a similar result? (I've tried setting the process priority of my app to "high", but it made no difference).

Comment: Like I said above, the quick and dirty approach is not to depend on windows for scheduling, in other words: don't call sleep (or other blocking calls). Yes, you will consume a ton of CPU, yes the OS may still yank the CPU from you to service other things (thus you are still not guaranteed to meet your timing requirements 100% of the time), but you will meet them most of the time... that is about as good as you can get without going to a real time system...